# Does npm publish command commit changes?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I can see at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages, that `npm version <update_type>` changes the version number in `package.json` (also add a tag with this release number to your git repository if you have one). Then, with `npm publish` the change is commited and the package updated.

I have a repository in Github which is published in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/).

The question is: do I have to commit my changes 
explicitly before `npm version <update_type>` or `npm publish`, or will `npm publish` take care of it.

This is an example of how I proceed now:

- Make some changes
- Execute the next commands:

`git add .`

`git commit -m "Message"`

`npm version minor`

`npm publish`

This is what I'm not sure if will work:

- Make some changes
- Execute the next commands:

`npm version minor`

`npm publish`

**Edit:**

In fact, if I execute `npm version minor` without committing the changes before, I get this error:

> npm ERR! Git working directory not clean.

So the answer would be: *Yes, I have to commit my changes explicitly before `npm version <update_type>`.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The question is: do I have to commit my changes explicitly before npm
>   version  or npm publish, or will npm publish take care of
>   it.

**The act of publishing to NPM is independent from committing and pushing to a Git repo.**

So, no, you do not *need* to commit before publishing, and NPM will not commit for you.

But, you *should* still strive to have your Git repository match your NPM versions. For example, you could tag important commits that correspond to a particular release.